# $1)$ when is $P^i + P^j$ is a symmetric matrix .? $2)$when is $P^i + P^j$ is a Normal matrix .?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let P be the $n\times n$  permutation matrices

$P=\left(\begin{matrix} 
  0 & 1 & 0 & ... & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 1 & ... & 0\\
  0 & 0& 0 & ... & 0\\  . & .& . & ... & 0\\
  0& 0 & 0 & ... & 1\\
  1 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0\\
\end{matrix}\right)$

$1)$ when is $P^i  + P^j$ is  a  symmetric matrix .?

$2)$when is  $P^i  + P^j$ is  a  Normal matrix .?

My attempts   :  i was  thinking  about  $PP^T = I$, But  i didn't get  any clues  in my my minds

Pliz help me

Any hints/solution  will be appreciated

thanks in advance

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $0\le i,j<n$ because $P^n=I=P^0$, hence the powers of $P$ repeat with period $n$.

We have (by induction)
$$ P^i= \begin{pmatrix}0 & I_{n-i} \\ I_i & 0\end{pmatrix} $$.

If $P^i$ is symmetric ($i\in\left\{0,\frac{n}{2}\right\}$) then $P^i+P^j$ is symmetric iff $P^j$ is. Otherwise, the same diagonals in the upper and lower triangle need to be covered, i.e. $i+j=n$.

Now $P^i+P^j$ is normal by definition iff $(P^i+P^j)(P^i+P^j)^T=(P^i+P^j)^T(P^i+P^j)$, i.e. $P^i{P^i}^T+P^j{P^i}^T+P^i{P^j}^T+P^j{P^j}^T={P^i}^TP^i+{P^j}^TP^i+{P^i}^TP^j+{P^j}^TP^j$. Using your identity $P^TP=I=PP^T$ (repeatedly), and assuming WLOG $i\ge j$, this is equivalent to ${P^{i-j}}^T+P^{i-j}=P^{i-j}+{P^{i-j}}^T$.

Hence, for $i,j\in\mathbb{Z}$, $P^i+P^j$ is always normal, and it is symmetric iff $(i,j\bmod n)\in\left\{0,\frac{n}{2}\right\}$ or $i+j\equiv 0\pmod n$.